ng-bootstrap table: how to select a range of rows with SHIFT key?
how to select a range of rows in a ng-bootstrap table with SHIFT key ?
(in the same way as react-data-grid)

It does not support selection features, you can request a feature request on their github page. If it has enough votes it will be implemented in the future.
